# Is there a link between fibromyalgia and sugar intake?

Tags: sugar, correlation, reference-request, fibromyalgia

I've seen 2 women suffering from a fibromyalgic syndrome who tried to drastically suppress all sugar in their diet. The pain went from 7/10 to 3/10.

After some reviews on forums I found other cases of success of such diets. I also found cases where it was not a success.

Is there any insights that could explain this ?

Answer (score 3):

The following is what I have found, which shows promise on your hypothesis.

[Yanmaz, at al. (2012)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00296-010-1618-8) found

> an increased prevalence rate of [Fibromyalgia Syndrome] in patients with [diabetes mellitus] type 2 and [rheumatoid arthritis]. There was no correlation between the prevalence rate of [Fibromyalgia Syndrome] and good [diabetes mellitus] disease control.

A pilot study by [Mengshoel, et al. (1995)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02214937) followed a 10-week multi-disciplinary approach which involved exercise and cognitive approaches.

For the cognitive approach, they looked at patient knowledge of fibromyalgia and instructed on diet.

> According to the food records, the dietician informed about good food habits and suggested dietary improvements such as: intake of four regular meals a day, increased intake of fruits and vegetables, increased intake of fluid and reduced intake of sweets and sugar.

All patients (*n*=16)

> showed improvements for all variables after ten weeks.

They also said that **controlled studies are needed** in the future.

### References

Mengshoel, A. M., Forseth, K. Ø., Haugen, M., Walle-Hansen, R., & Førre, Ø. (1995). Multidisciplinary approach to fibromyalgia A pilot study. *Clinical rheumatology*, 14(2), 165-170. doi: [10.1007/BF02214937](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02214937)

Yanmaz, M. N., Mert, M., & Korkmaz, M. (2012). The prevalence of fibromyalgia syndrome in a group of patients with diabetes mellitus. *Rheumatology international*, 32(4), 871-874. doi: [10.1007/s00296-010-1618-8](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00296-010-1618-8)